# Cannot deserialize ObservableDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, serialization

I use ObservableDictionary class from Dr.WPF and I need to serialize and deserialize this collection. Serialization goes well, but when I try to deserialize it throw an exception:

```
$exception  {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}   System.Exception {System.NullReferenceException}
StackTrace  "   at EngineConfigurationManager.ObservableDictionary.ObservableDictionary`2.AddEntry(TKey key, TValue value) in d:\\Доки\\Editor\\EngineConfigurationManager\\EngineConfigurationManager\\ObservableDictionary\\ObservableDictionary.cs:line 196\r\n   at EngineConfigurationManager.ObservableDictionary.ObservableDictionary`2.OnDeserialization(Object sender) in d:\\Доки\\Editor\\EngineConfigurationManager\\EngineConfigurationManager\\ObservableDictionary\\ObservableDictionary.cs:line 592\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.RaiseDeserializationEvent()\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)\r\n   at EngineConfigurationManager.ConfigClasses.Camera.CameraConfigurationManager.Load() in d:\\Доки\\Editor\\EngineConfigurationManager\\EngineConfigurationManager\\ConfigClasses\\Camera\\CameraConfigurationManager.cs:line 936" string
```

I tried to debug mentioned method

```
public virtual void OnDeserialization(object sender)
    {
        if (_siInfo != null)
        {
            Collection<DictionaryEntry> entries = (Collection<DictionaryEntry>)
                _siInfo.GetValue("entries", typeof(Collection<DictionaryEntry>));
            foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in entries)
                AddEntry((TKey)entry.Key, (TValue)entry.Value);
        }
    }

protected KeyedDictionaryEntryCollection<TKey> _keyedEntryCollection;

protected virtual bool AddEntry(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        _keyedEntryCollection.Add(new DictionaryEntry(key, value));
        return true;
    }
```

but I cannot find any error: key and value are not empty or null.

Does anyone knows what is the reason of the problem?

**Edit:**
There are few constructors in ObservableDictionary class, but I think deserialization doesnt invoke any of them.

```
public ObservableDictionary()
    {
        _keyedEntryCollection = new KeyedDictionaryEntryCollection<TKey>();
    }

    public ObservableDictionary(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary)
    {
        _keyedEntryCollection = new KeyedDictionaryEntryCollection<TKey>();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> entry in dictionary)
            DoAddEntry((TKey)entry.Key, (TValue)entry.Value);
    }

    public ObservableDictionary(IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
    {
        _keyedEntryCollection = new KeyedDictionaryEntryCollection<TKey>(comparer);
    }

    public ObservableDictionary(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
    {
        _keyedEntryCollection = new KeyedDictionaryEntryCollection<TKey>(comparer);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> entry in dictionary)
            DoAddEntry((TKey)entry.Key, (TValue)entry.Value);
    }
```

I can make so:

```
protected KeyedDictionaryEntryCollection<TKey> _keyedEntryCollection = new        KeyedDictionaryEntryCollection<TKey>();
```

but I don`t think this is correct way.
I deserialize collection this way:
    CombinedCameraContainer = (ObservableDictionary) binaryFormatter.Deserialize(fs);

Is there something you can suggest me in this situation?

Comment: As I see problem is in `AddEntry`, not in OnDeserialization. Post code of AddEntry.

Comment: Here is the code for AddEntry. I edited post

Comment: The exception stack trace pinpoints the error to `ObservableDictionary.cs` line 196. A reference used in that line of code is `null` when you get the exception.

Comment: line 196 its _keyedEntryCollection.Add(new DictionaryEntry(key, value)); But key and value is not null. Thats the point. I don`t know what is null here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments this is the line that throws the exception:

```
_keyedEntryCollection.Add(new DictionaryEntry(key, value));
```

The only reference that is dereferenced in that line is `_keyedEntryCollection` so that must be `null`.

To solve your problem you need to initialize the `_keyedEntryCollection` field when the instance is constructed:

```
protected KeyedDictionaryEntryCollection<TKey> _keyedEntryCollection
  = new KeyedDictionaryEntryCollection<TKey>();
```

Or you can perform the initialization in an appropriate constructor instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that most probably ObservableDictionary uses KeyValuePair as its underlying item type. This class is immutable so it cannot be constructed with a parameterless constructor and then have its Key and Value members set. So, it cannot be used with most deserializers which expect such behavior.

Comment: But I can serialize it with standart BinaryFormatter! 
Does I really couldnt deserialize it as usual?

Comment: Serializing is not an issue, to serialize, you read the key and value properties and write them to your serialization context. However, when you read the serialized data, the deserializer instantiates a KeyValuePair without any parameters, then tries to set them to the values it read from the data. For classes like KeyValuePair<,> this fails, so the values remain null